# Bulk image downloading with optimized way

Tags: java, swing, executorservice

I'm having an web site say somthing.com developed in spring MVC and one client desktop application developed in Swing Java.  I want to download bulk images from server URL like.

```
somthing.com/resourse/webfiles/imgs/1.jpg
somthing.com/resourse/webfiles/imgs/2.jpg
somthing.com/resourse/webfiles/imgs/3.jpg
...
somthing.com/resourse/webfiles/imgs/n.jpg
```

For testing purpose I installed client in several PC's and given hit to server but avg. it takes 20 mins to download 1800 imgs/PC.

Is there any faster way to do this?

The current code/login steps are...(sorry for not giving actual code..)

- Requesting image URL.
- Fetching response in output stream.
- then taking byte and looping it to write images in physical location.

Comment: Isn't your image downloading rate contingent on internet speed? Apart from that, I would suggest using NIO.

Comment: take the size of the 1800 images and the time it takes and calculate the throughput you actually get in MB/s or so. Compare that to the theoretical bandwidth limit between app and server (or whatever is the bottleneck, could even be hdd writing speed)

Comment: How big are the images?  Your numbers give you about 1.5 images / second, which is pretty bad if the images are 2-3KB each, and pretty fast if they're 10MB each.

Comment: @IanMcLaird, yes you are correct per image size is 2-4KB.

Comment: Why on Earth is the Swing app. downloading 1800 images?  What are they used for?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server, just copy the files to a USB thumbdrive and then copy them to every pc. This could be much faster.

Actually, I would assume with your approach the bandwidth between the client pc and the server is th limit, not your code.

Potentially, it could help to do some multithreading. But I would not think this will increase the throughput more than a few percent if the network bandwidth is the limit.

You can quickly check if there is any potential for improvement by this calculation: What is your connection bandwidth, and how does this compare to the total transferred bytes in twenty minutes? For simplicity, i would calculate 10 bits to one byte of real transferred data, to take care of the protocol overhead.

Comment: :) thanks for ur reply...but as my server application is hosted some where else and my desktop application may installed on various PC's/learing centers (approx 5480) at different location...and on server images get uploaded by topic expert which will learing centers download them...